# Column and line based modification using bash

Tags: awk, sed

I have one file that contains 1,000,000 lines as shown in "input" below. 
I want to trim the 3rd column which contains from domains, URLs, URNs, URIs to just a domain name.
I want to do it on Debian using bash.

Input:

> k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP0,10,someurl.ds/dsadsa/dsadsads.exe/,This is bad
>   url_feed k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP1,10,http://www.someurl.ds:2331,This is
>   bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP2,10,https://someurl.ds/dsadsa/dsadsads.exe/,This
>   is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP3,10,someurl.ds/dsadsa/http/test/com,This is bad
>   url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP4,10,a.b.c.d.someurl.ds/dsadsa/dsadsads.exe/,This
>   is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP5,10,anythingelse.someurl.ds/dsadsa/dsadsads.exe/,This
>   is bad url_feed

Output:

> k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP0,10,someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP1,10,www.someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP2,10,someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP3,10,someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP4,10,a.b.c.d.someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed
>   k285N2YBqOyRFMJBdrP5,10,anythingelse.someurl.ds,This is bad url_feed

I am reducing the 3rd column as I want with:

```
cat test3.txt | cut -d"," -f3 | sed -E -e 's_.*://([^/@]*@)?([^/:]+).*_\2_' | cut -d "/" -f1
```

How can I extract the 3rd column, modify and return on the place?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this with perl or awk?

Comment: Try `awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { sub(/.*:\/\/([^\/@]*@)?/, "", $3); sub(/[\/:].*/, "", $3); print; }'  file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { sub(/.*:\/\/([^\/@]*@)?/, "", $3); sub(/[\/:].*/, "", $3); print; }' file > outfile
```

Here,

- `BEGIN { OFS=FS="," }` will set field separator to `,`
- `sub(/.*:\/\/([^\/@]*@)?/, "", $3)` will remove the part of Column 3 value at the start that you do not need
- `sub(/[\/:].*/, "", $3)` will remove trailing part of Column 3 value you do not need

Note that instead of `print` command, you may use `1` after `}` (this is the same thing in the end, it prints the current record): `'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { sub(/.*:\/\/([^\/@]*@)?/, "", $3); sub(/[\/:].*/, "", $3); }1'`.

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/LUbFKH).

Comment: Very solid solution. My file was processed 100% properly.time awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS="," } { sub(/.*:\/\/([^\/@]*@)?/, "", $3); sub(/[\/:].*/, "", $3); print; }' export.csv  > 1234.txt

real    0m0.901s
user    0m0.688s
sys     0m0.208s
wc -l 1234.txt
1013861 1234.txt